# GWT (2.7) Compile fails when declaring a GwtQuery (1.0.6) Widget in UiBinder in GWTP (1.5.1) project

Tags: maven, gwt, uibinder, gwtp, gwtquery

When I simply just declare a GwtQuery DragAndDropCellTree in my MyView.ui.xml UiBinder in my GWTP project, I cannot GWT Compile it:

```
[3]  xmlns:gq="urn:import:gwtquery.plugins.droppable.client.gwt"
...
[59]       <gq:DragAndDropCellTree></gq:DragAndDropCellTree>
```

> [ERROR] No class matching "DragAndDropCellTree" in urn:import:gwtquery.plugins.droppable.client.gwt: < gq:DragAndDropCellTree > (:59)
>
> [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/my/package/com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java'
>   [ERROR] Failed to resolve 'my.package.MyView.Binder' via deferred binding
>
> [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
>   [WARN] my.package.MyView_BinderImpl

I followed [GwtQuery Configuration](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#Configuration) using Maven in Eclipse.
I'm not sure if my problem lies in GWT, GWTP, Maven, or GwtQuery

*Any ideas what I am doing wrong?*

- Without the declaration, but with the import in the UiBinder of gwtquery.plugins.droppable.client.gwt, I can successfully compile
- I can successfully compile when making the declaration in MyView.java instead of UiBinder
- I cannot compile when declaring any other DragAndDrop either, nor when declaring one in a different UiBinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this one out.
[Any Widget used in UiBinder must have a zero-arg constructor](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget)...

DragAndDropCellTree does not have a zero-arg constructor.  So it makes sense that I could declare in MyView.java but not MyView.ui.xml.

So this was a GWT <-> GwtQuery problem.

These are [alternatives to still use UiBinder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget).